# How do I bind an event to the left mouse button being held down?

Tags: python, tkinter, event-binding

I need a command to be executed as long as the left mouse button is being held down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at table 7-1 of the docs. There are events that specify motion while the button is pressed, `<B1-Motion>`, `<B2-Motion>` etc.

If you're not talking about a press-and-move event, then you can start doing your activity on `<Button-1>` and stop doing it when you receive `<B1-Release>`.

Comment: I would recommend keeping a variable like `mouse_is_down` and set it to `True` or `False` depending on whether or not you receive the press or release event. In your code, during the loop you can check to see if the variable is `True`, meaning the mouse is down, and do your thing for a button hold. When the variable is `False`, you can skip your code for mouse button holding.

Comment: Apparently now the link should be: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: @JesseDhillon The problem with that is when you move the mouse out of the window

Answer (score 10):

If you want "something to happen" without any intervening events (ie: without the user moving the mouse or pressing any other buttons) your only choice is to poll. Set a flag when the button is pressed, unset it when released. While polling, check the flag and run your code if its set.

Here's something to illustrate the point:

```
import Tkinter

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.mouse_pressed = False
        f = Tkinter.Frame(width=100, height=100, background="bisque")
        f.pack(padx=100, pady=100)
        f.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.OnMouseDown)
        f.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.OnMouseUp)

    def do_work(self):
        x = self.root.winfo_pointerx()
        y = self.root.winfo_pointery()
        print "button is being pressed... %s/%s" % (x, y)

    def OnMouseDown(self, event):
        self.mouse_pressed = True
        self.poll()

    def OnMouseUp(self, event):
        self.root.after_cancel(self.after_id)

    def poll(self):
        if self.mouse_pressed:
            self.do_work()
            self.after_id = self.root.after(250, self.poll)

root=Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**However**, polling is generally not necessary in a GUI app. You probably only care about what happens while the mouse is pressed *and* is moving. In that case, instead of the poll function simply bind do_work to a `<B1-Motion>` event.

Answer (score 2):

Use the mouse move/motion events and check the modifier flags. The mouse buttons will show up there.