# How do i bind "mouse is pressed" in Python's tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseclick-event

I'm new to tkinter and I'm coding a simple "Paint" program, that draws a pixel on screen when I press my mouse.

So i tried to bind my function "is_pressed" like this:

```
#is pressed
def is_pressed(event):
    print('Mouse is pressed!')

#creating canvas
my_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(height=400, width=600)
my_canvas.pack()

#binding
my_canvas.bind('<Button-1>', is_pressed)
```

Now, I want this function to run when mouse is pressed, not when it's just clicked. How do i do it?

Comment: Here are some good examples of how it woks with the full code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288001/how-do-i-bind-an-event-to-the-left-mouse-button-being-held-down

Comment: Oh, the "<B1-Motion>" works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like 'painting' with the mouse, I've usually used `bind('<B1-Motion>', <callback>)`

Naturally, you can bind this to other buttons using `B2` or `B3` instead.

The caveat here is that the event doesn't trigger immediately - you have to move the mouse first. You could easily bind a second handler to `<'Button-1'>` though

```
# this should catch the moment the mouse is pressed as well as any motion while the
# button is held; the lambdas are just examples - use whatever callback you want
my_canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda e: print(e))
my_canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e: print(e))
```

Comment: Glad to help out! If this answer worked for you, please mark it as “accepted” so that others know this question has been answered. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The event you need to bind to is `<ButtonPress-1>`, if you want to call a function when the button is pressed.

If you want to continuously call a function when the mouse is moved while the button is pressed, then you can bind to `<B1-Motion>`. That would allow you to draw as the user moves the mouse around.

Comment: @WojtekSmelcerz I absolutely guarantee it’s the correct event to bind to. This isn’t an opinion, it’s a fact. If it’s not working, you’re doing something wrong. Without seeing what you did, it’s impossible for me to guess.

Comment: @WojtekSmelcerz If you’re wanting to do something while the button is pressed _and moving_ you can use `<B1-Motion>`